# The Loss number of both train set and validation set both went down at the begining and then went up again

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, adam, siamese-network, learning-rate

I try to use the siamese network which combines with two resnet networks (Pretrained) to solve the few shot problem. The loss function is **contrassive loss** and the optimizer is **Adam with 0.001 learning rate**.

Both train set loss and validation loss went down since the experiment beginning and the model reached its best results at **about 450 epochs.**

However, When the experiment keep running, both numbers began to rise and to the same extent as they had at the beginning of the experiment.

- [Picture of train loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofm4r.png)
- [Picture of val loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjk7w.png)
- [Picture of train acc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcamf.png)
- [Picture of val acc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prVoa.png)

I don't think it was a overfit problem, is there anyone who knows what happen? How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example# that shows what you are doing and some information about the data sets you are using. That will help people trouble-shoot what is going on.

Comment: Looks like a question cross validated answers on the regular. Example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292700/overfitting-in-neural-network